# How to create custom block rendering with draft js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am trying to add custom blocks in the Editor area. I am able to create blocks but not getting the html output of those block elements. I am using "draft-to-html" package to convert the contentState to html data.

Adding the codesandbox link -- Can anyone suggest how can i achieve the same or if there is any alternate way to do it

[trying to create Custom blocks inside draft editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0a3O.png)

codesandbox Link : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/draft-js-custom-block-component-forked-q7t6zk

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.